# how to upload images on mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a shopping website using php and mysql. I am trying to upload and save an image to mysql database. Whenever i upload the image it does not store in the database. i have been figuring this out for a few days. When i run this code the image does not save and an error message appears saying 'Error While uploading image on the server'

php code

```
<?php

include("common.php");

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)

     {

       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;

       switch($imagetype)

       {

           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';

           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';

           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';

           case 'image/png': return '.png';

           default: return false;

       }

     }

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];

    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];

    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];

    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);

    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;

    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

    $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES

('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')"; 

 mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error()); 

}else{
exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 
}
?>;
```

Form

```
    <form action="testing.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">

<tbody><tr>

<td>

<input name="uploadedimage" type="file">

</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image">

</td>

</tr>

</body></table>

</form>
```

Comment: I would say the error is when he tries to do : `move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)`. Do you have error display turned on with error_reporting set to E_ALL ?

Comment: If you don't have permission to write to the target folder (images/ in this case), that would trigger an error and make the error message to appear. Make sure you have the right permissions on that folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with quotes in your query.

Do something like

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
"INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date) VALUES ('{$target_path}', '{$date}')";
```